# Копирование датафрейма Pandas. Зачем нужна опция deep?

Tags: python, pandas

Добрый день.

Объясните, пожалуйста, зачем нужна опция `deep` при копировании датафрейма в Pandas?

В документации как-то невнятно написано, подчёркивается только, что для датафреймов глубокое копирование не является аналогом глубокого копирование обычных объектов питона. Но чем тогда отличаются варианты `deep=True` и `deep=False` - я не понял.

Если мне нужно просто взять один исходный датафрейм и получить его копию, чтобы я мог модифицировать исходник и копию независимо друг от друга - то какое значение опции `deep` я должен указать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы быть уверенным, что данные ваших фреймов независимы, лучше воспользоваться `DataFrame.copy(deep=True)` (`deep=True` - по умолчанию).

Пример:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3), columns=list('abc'))

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8

In [13]: df2 = df.copy(deep=True)

In [15]: df2.loc[:, 'a'] = 100

In [16]: df2
Out[16]:
     a  b  c
0  100  1  2
1  100  4  5
2  100  7  8

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```

PS в Pandas 0.20.1+ у меня так и не получилось воспроизвести проблему "зависимых" фреймов...

Comment: То есть, если я хочу работать с копиями, как с независимыми объектами, лучше всего просто не указывать эту опцию?

Comment: @Александр, да, либо не указывать, либо указывать явно `deep=True` - это дело вкуса...